# Cannot import ViewFrame in Vaadin 14.6.8

Tags: vaadin14

I'm quite new to Vaadin and currently developing with Vaadin 14.6.8. I tried to use ViewFrame in my project, but my Eclipse seems does not recognized it. I tried to find where this class located and its package online but not found any useful information. Is it a paid version of Vaadin feature?

My Eclipse shows: ViewFrame cannot be resolved to a type

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewFrame` is a helper class that isn't part of the core Vaadin platform but instead belongs to the commercial [Business App starter](https://vaadin.com/start/v14/business-app) that provides a highly opinionated starting point for Vaadin applications.